# Gradle Java Compile: "Implicitly compiled files were not subject to annotation processing"

Tags: java, android, gradle, annotations

I use the gradle java plugin. My Java code contains annotation processing. When I execute the `compileJava` task I get the following warning:

```
:compileJavawarning: Implicitly compiled files were not subject to annotation 

processing.
  Use -implicit to specify a policy for implicit compilation.
1 warning
```

**How can I prevent this warning and what does it mean?**

Comment: I don't think that helps.  you are just echoing what the message says.

What are implicitly compiled files?  How do you pass in the -implicit arg?  Is it a gradle or javac argument?

Comment: Funny that you are asking that, @tdugan. I’m sure all these were the questions that the OP had when he created this question.